# When is the value outside a clusure in golang to be used?

Tags: go, closures

```
var loggers []*logOutput = nil

func init() {
    loggers = make([]*logOutput, int(LOGGER_USAGE_TYPE_COUNT))
}

func ABC() {
    loggers[loggerType].ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second * 
    time.Duration(logRotateCheckInterval))
    go func() {
        defer RecoverFunc()
        for {
            <-loggers[loggerType].ticker.C
            loggers[loggerType].checkAndRotateLogFile()
        }
    }()
}
```

`<-loggers[loggerType].ticker.C` will sometimes panic. And there's only one goroutine modifying `loggers[loggerType]` and `loggers[loggerType].ticker`.
I found that when panic happens, `loggers[loggerType].ticker` is `nil`, which makes me feel that the goroutine use the value of `loggers[loggerType].ticker` before `loggers[loggerType].ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second * 
        time.Duration(logRotateCheckInterval))` is executed.

Could anyone explain when the closure takes the value of a outside variable?
I change the logger as a pointer variable to the goroutine func as a solution

Comment: Please show all your code, and if possible past a link to go playground (https://github.com/plutov/playgo). So people can run and test your code, now I see missing vars like `loggerType`, `LOGGER_USAGE_TYPE_COUNT `, etc.

Comment: As above, your code is incomplete. Where does the `loggerType` index come from? This should really be a function parameter in `ABC()`. If this is some sort of global variable, it's likely being changed before your new go-routine has started. You've got to watch how you access variables with concurrency.

Comment: Can you turn this into a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably on the [Go playground](http://play.golang.org)?

Comment: Run your code with the race detector. You have a global map being accessed by goroutines, and any modification to the map during execution will be a data race.